# qmail に設定したドメインを変えたい

Tags: qmail

qmailを使用しています。
今回、メールアドレスの `mail@example.com` という `example.com` を変更したいのですが、controlフォルダ内のファイルを変えてもドメインが変更されません。

聞きたい事は、ドメインを変えるファイルが何かと、設定反映はファイル更新後に反映されるのか？ご指導お願い致します。

Comment: qmail デーモン (プロセス) の再起動は実施しましたか？私自身は qmail を使った事がないので憶測を含みますが、qmail に限らずこの手のサーバプログラム (いわゆるデーモン) は設定変更後には再起動が必要なことが多いです。

Comment: 新ドメインのMXレコードの設定は済んでいるのでしょうか。ドメインが変更されていない、ということはどうやって確認しましたか。